# A good "design pattern" for navigation sidebar in jsf

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm looking for a good design "pattern" for a sidebar navigation menu in jsf.
I really wanted to use `rich:menuPanel` but it is limited in too many ways (Mainly, that if i use `rich:menuPanelItem` I can't make the icons any other size than the default 16x16.

So... Anyone has a good one?
TnX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can adjust every aspect of any richfaces component through CSS, so using it and changing the height/width properties using CSS should just help you do what you want

Comment: I don't think.I tried to do this with CSS in every way I knew how and didn't manage. Perhaps you know where to look better..?

Comment: To tell you the truth, I havent done what I toold you to do with richFaces, but I've done it with PrimeFaces and it is a matter of loading the right CSS sheet the last. That is, load your custom styles after richfaces has loaded their. Also you could try using the !important modifier in CSS. so if richfaces has a p {color: red;} you could overwrite thise by putting in your css sheet p {color: blue !important; } this way your rule will be prefered over others